# How are astronauts aboard the Tiangong space station keeping busy?

Tags: planetary-science, photography, imaging, measurement, optical

Per Wikipedia's [Tiangong space station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station) viewed today:

- Days in orbit:    3 months, 15 days  (13 August 2021)
- Days occupied:    1 month,  27 days  (13 August 2021)

Currently it is just the single core module. There have been supply missions and there's currently a crew:

- Fully crewed: 3
- Currently aboard: 3

**Question:** Two months in a single space station module sounds challenging; how are astronauts aboard the Tiangong space station keeping busy?

---

For reference, this is from way back in June, shortly after arrival:

[A day in the life of taikonauts at the CSS](https://news.cgtn.com/news/2021-06-23/A-day-in-the-life-of-taikonauts-at-the-CSS-11kwc3SBvAQ/index.html)

> The China space station is up and running with three astronauts, or taikonauts, living in it.
>
> Life in the station has been improved much compared to previous Chinese crewed spacecrafts, with a larger living room and bedrooms, more advanced space suits and more.
>
> The first few days in the space station were dedicated to the unpacking of supplies, especially those from the Tianzhou-2 supply ship. Though working more than eight hours a day, the three taikonauts can still enjoy naps during the noon break. There's also an automatic lighting system to keep a healthy inner clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information on the taikonauts' daily work is extremely sparse. I don't think a full timeline or schedule for the Shenzhou-12 mission is public. Here is what I can find among Chinese media (mostly CCTV).

1. First week: unpack supplies, setup living environment. Setup WiFi on 6-20.
2. 6-23 Telephone with President Xi.
3. 6-30 Send celebration message to ground, 100th anniversary of CCP.
4. 07-04 EVA. Setup robotic arm and EV work station. Raise EV camera. Total EVA time: 7 hours.
5. 7-16 (A typical day) Routine check on the spacecraft. Collect trace elements in the atmosphere. Replace CO2 absorber canisters. Workout. Meeting with ground control and plan for the next day
6. 7-17 Unpack human system experiment equipment. Start a series of 49 experiments, 14 to be completed by Shenzhou-12 crew.
7. 7-23 to 8-8 (Among other things) Watch Olympics.

Comment: Aside from snippets like this: https://twitter.com/China2ASEAN/status/1424309417877508101 - they keep a pretty tight lid on things there. Showing good 'face' is very important in the culture.

Comment: It seems there's been another space walk recently as well.